# Using named query inside entity method in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity that has a @ManyToMany collection marked as lazy. When I list those entities in a JSP I call a method in each entity to decide if I should show a button or not, that method was developed to count the number of elements in that collection, so if the number of elements is too high it takes forever to show the JSP because Hibernate loads the entire collection with all of their data.

I was wondering if there's a way to call a NamedQuery from that method in the entity, for example:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="showButton",
    query="SELECT count(distinct(id)) FROM USER where GROUP_ID = :groupId")
@Entity 
class Group {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    ...
    public boolean showButton() {
        // Can I call the named query here??
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a ManyToMany field for Group in the User entity so that you can get the count by joining users to group using HQL.

Comment: I have that field, but how do I get the count from the showButton method in Group? Because I need this method to be called from the JSP that lists the Groups. I enable or disable that button depending on what showButton() returns.

Comment: backwards.  the entity shouldn't know about external business rules.  create an object that executes the methodology on the entity bean.  remember, entities are just for mashalling/unmarshalling data.  business logic belongs outside (as a controller, decoration, etc.) the entity.

Comment: Well, that's not business logic, only a calculated property, like anyother, like if I wanted to calculate how many users belonged to the group, or what colour should be the button for each Group.... I found @Formula annotation to be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NamedQuery is not possible, but @Formula can be used to calculate a property.